# How to Redraw 3D content in WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, 3d, drawing

So I have a bunch of lines that I have drawn using the ScreenSpaceLines3D class provided by http://3dtools.codeplex.com/

I was able to draw lines to my Viewport by defining them like

```
Point3D point0 = new Point3D(0, 0, 0);    
Point3D point1 = new Point3D(5, 5, 0);    
Point3D point2 = new Point3D(5, 5.5, 0);
```

and inside a button_click method, basically draw a bunch of lines like

```
ScreenSpaceLines3D wireframe = new ScreenSpaceLines3D();    
wireframe.Points.Add(point0);    
wireframe.Points.Add(point1);    
wireframe.Points.Add(point2);    
wireframe.Color = Colors.LightBlue;    
wireframe.Thickness = 5;    
this.mainViewport.Children.Add(wireframe);
```

I have also added a `point1.Z += 2;` to see a change in the lines after every click.

I want to see only the same set of lines shifting, but new sets of lines end up getting draw after every click. I only need to refresh/redraw the same set with an updated set of points. I tried using `InvalidateVisual();` and `InvalidateArrange();` but did not work.

Please advise!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no Invalidate function. You have to clear ScreenSpaceLine3d points and than update the points.

```
public MainWindow()  
{  
    ScreenSpaceLines3D wireframe = new ScreenSpaceLines3D();  
    wireframe.Color = Colors.LightBlue;  
    wireframe.Thickness = 5;   
    this.mainViewport.Children.Add(wireframe);  
}

public void CustomInvalidate( Point3DCollection point)  
{  
    if (wireframe!= null)  
            {  
                wireframe.Points.Clear();  
            }  
    wireframe.Points.Add(point[0]);    
    wireframe.Points.Add(point[1]);    
    wireframe.Points.Add(point[2]);  
}
```